# PHP: How efficient is caching loaded data in static variables or class properties?

Tags: php, oop, caching, static

I have encountered both functions and class methods which store loaded data into a static variable or a class property by ID, and checks if the ID exists in the variable/property before continuing. If the ID exists, it returns the "cached" data from the variable/property. If it doesn't, it loads the data and then stores it in the variable/property.

```
class MyProducts {
  public $products = array();
```

And then the loader method looks like:

```
public function loadProduct($product_id) {
  if(isset($this->products[$product_id])) return $this->products[$product_id];
  // otherwise do all the data loading into $product_data; pretend code is
  // here to pull data; now store it
  $this->products[$product_id] = $product_data;
}
```

I've also seen it done directly in a function like so:

```
function loadProduct($product_id) {
  static $myproducts = array();
  if(isset($myproducts[$product_id])) return $myproducts[$product_id];
  // otherwise do all the data loading into $product_data; pretend code is
  // here to pull data; now store it
  $myproducts[$product_id] = $product_data;
}
```

How efficient is this and how long does the "cached" data last? I've tried reading a few articles on the subject and still end up confused. I know we do leverage memcache and there was some mention of it in th articles I read.

Thanks!

Comment: In the first example `$myproducts` is available in any method in the class by `$this->myproducts`. In the second example `$myproducts` is only available in that function and nowhere else.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I just learned the data only persists through the current script execution. In the examples I gave, we only load the product data once so it appears to be pointless. However, I've also seen it used to cache configured settings which are loaded multiple times throughout execution, so I can definitely see the advantage there.

Comment: Be careful with `static` variables inside class methods; the values will **not** be per-instance, but shared for *any* invokation: https://3v4l.org/X6aJL.

Comment: If it's costly to calculate and/or retrieve there's still value in caching within the execution if you're going to touch it multiple times, but if you need it cached _between_ executions then you probably need something like Redis or Memcached to persist that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Jeto I remembered reading something about that, I believe that's where these variables may have been more useful in some of our work in the past.